# CloudFormation cfn-init.exe command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I saw the following code in the begining of the userdata script. What is it for?

```
if (${PROXY}) {
    &"cfn-init.exe" -v -s ${STACK_ID} -r ${RESOURCE} --region ${REGION} --http-proxy=${PROXY} --https-proxy=${PROXY}
} else {
    write-host "Unable to determine Proxy setting"
    &"cfn-init.exe" -v -s ${STACK_ID} -r ${RESOURCE} --region ${REGION}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"cfn-init.exe" is a utility from cloudformation to execute instance initialization provisioning defined in cloudformation template .

This ensures the server initialization configurations defined under "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" section inside the cloud formation template is executed.

Please check the following documentation for reference
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html

Comment: Hi I know what cfn-init is but what does above code do? I saw it in the begining of a powershell userdata script

Comment: The instance must have been generated using cloud formation, you will need to check cloudformation template for the stack, and check what has been defined under AWS::CloudFormation::Init section.